# Multiple rows in header in kendo mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How I can display the second word of header in column?

Now kendo grid doesnt show symbols which dont place in header

I want

```
Second
First
```

But now

```
Second Fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this CSS to allow the column header text to wrap when column width too small to display all words:

```
  th.k-header{
    white-space: normal !important;
  }
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/eDADU)**